# remove value from the list

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery

I have a running value list which is built by clicking on a set of check boxes. Upon unchecking the check box the value is removed from the list. This piece works fine.

Also when I check the option the text is added to the selected section. When I uncheck the option I want that selection option to be removed. If the selected option was deleted I need to uncheck the checkbox and remove the value from the running list.

```
$(".myCheckboxClass").change(function() {       
  var list = $('#bodyIDList').data('value');
  if( $(this).is(":checked") ) {list.push( $(this).val());          
    var text = $('label[for=' + $(this).val() + ']').text();    
    $("#selectedListSelected").append('<label></label>');
    $("#selectedListSelected").append('<ul class="options"><li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">' + text + '</li></ul>');           
  } else {
    var index = list.indexOf($(this).val());        
    list.splice(index, 1);                  
    $(this).closest('ul').remove();         
  }     
  $("#bodyIDList").val(list);
});
```

Comment: could you post some of the HTML

Answer (score 0):

After you add the new selection, find out what the index number is in your array.  You can then assign a custom class to your UL tag.  If your array index is 7 then you could add a class like "arr7" to your UL:

```
var arrPosition = 'arr' + list.indexOf($(this).val());
$("#selectedListSelected").append('<ul class="options ' + arrPosition +'"><li onclick="this.parentNode.removeChild(this);">' + text + '</li></ul>');
```

When you are deleting the value from the array, you know the index so you can do a quick jQuery selector to get the right UL node and delete it:

```
var arrPosition = 'arr' + index;    
$('ul.' + arrPosition ).remove();
```